# Saving product deletes tier price and group price

Tags: magento-1.8, product-collection, tierprice, save, group-price

I've got a problem when programatically saving a product.

While loading the product with help of the product collection or the model (by attribute), setting some value and then saving it, I'm losing the tier and group prices.

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

One can do a workaround by doing one of these:

1.Reload each product:

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($product->getId());
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

2.Load tier and group price (source):

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->getTierPrice(); 
    $product->getGroupPrice();
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

minimal variant of reloading (for example) the tier price attribute (extracted from Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getTierPrice():

```
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');
if($attribute){
    $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
}
```

3.Add dummy values (source):

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->setTierPrice ( array (
        'website_id' => 0,
        'cust_group' => 2,
        'price_qty' => 3,
        'price' => 10 
    ) );
    $product->setGroupPrice ( array (
        'website_id' => 0,
        'cust_group' => 2,
        'price' => 10 
    ) );
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

All these workarounds have one problem: more database calls.
When often running scripts that update a lot of products, it is bad to have even more database calls only for **not** to lose the tier and group prices.

One can add the tier prices while building up the collection:

```
$productList = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->getCollection ()
  ->addFieldToFilter('color', $color)
  ->addTierPriceData()
  ->load();
foreach($productList as  $product) {
    $product->setColor($newColor);
    $product->save();
}
```

But by doing so, on save one will get a constraint violation error. It seems in this case Magento tries to save the exact same tier prices again.

Does anyone know a solution which loads the tier and group prices in the same query that is used by the product collection and does not trigger constraint violations on save?

I have also posted this question in the StackOverflow part of StackExchange:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900130/saving-product-deletes-tier-price-and-group-price

Answer (score 1):

you should never call `save` without calling `load` first on a product instance.
A `save` without a load (on a product from a collection for example) will lead to loss of data.
If you only want to update a single attribute value for a product do this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($attributeId),
    array('attribute_code' => 'attribute_value'),
    $storeId
);
```

`$storeId` is the storeview for which you want to update the value. For default values use `0`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to test this right now, as the Project is on ice. I'll see to it, that I can reproduce the problem and to check out your solution.

Comment: Hello @Marius , can you give me syntax for "tier_price" attribute for Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action') ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$product->setTierPrice ( array(array (
        'website_id' => 0,
        'cust_group' => 2,
        'price_qty' => 3,
        'price' => 10 
    )) );
```

Its should be array of arrays

Comment: This looks like the workaround no. 3 (which worked without an array of arrays). What I am looking for is a way to make an update to the product **without** touching it's tier and group prices.